# Why does a partially ordered set need to be reflexive?

Tags: relations

I understand that why a partially ordered set needs to be antisymmetric and transitive. I just can't see the logic behind why it has to be reflexive?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Can't it be greater than or equal to?

Comment: I read $a\le b$ as "$a$ smaller or equal than $b$", so I say that one. Of course, $\ge$ is itself a partial order, and in general if $R$ is a partial order then $R^{-1}$ defined by $aR^{-1}b\stackrel{\text{def}}\iff bRa$ is a partial order as well.

Answer (score 4):

Because it mimics the usual meaning of "smaller-or-equal-than". In fact, there is a "dual" notion of "strict partial order":

> A binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is a strict partial order if and only if:
>
> 1. $\forall x\in X,\ \neg xR x$
> 2. $\forall x,y\in X,\ (xRy\land yRx)\to x=y$
> 3. $\forall x,y,z\in X,\ (xR y\land yR z)\to xR z$

Notice that $[(1)\land (2)]$ could have been restated equivalently as $[\forall x,y\in X,\ (\neg xRy\lor \neg yRx)]$.

An instance of these is the usual "$<$" on $\Bbb R$. Just as the names and examples suggest:

- for any partial order $P$ on a set $X$ the relation $x\Bbb S_Py\stackrel{\text{def}}\iff (x Py\land x\ne y)$ is a strict partial order;
- for any strict partial order $S$ on a set $X$ the relation $x\Bbb P_Sy\stackrel{\text{def}}\iff (x Sy\lor x= y)$ is a partial order;
- for any partial order $P$ and for any strict partial order $S$, $\Bbb S_{\Bbb P_S}=S$ and $\Bbb P_{\Bbb S_P}=P$.

Comment: +1. Although I have a doubt. Does the binary relation involved in ordered set always has to be either $≤ $ or $≥$ , or it can be anything else too?

Comment: @William A commonly used partial order is [inclusion of sets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset), which is inherently different from the usual total order of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes but then if I'm not mistaken, if you use that, the set will only ever be a partially ordered and can never be a totally ordered set as law of trichotomy wouldn't apply. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It is indeed the case that the power set of a set with at least two elements is not totally ordered by $\subseteq$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time man. You been a big help. :)

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I actually had the same question as the original OP, and found this question and your answer.   But, I still don't understand it. Why would a partial order mirror something like $\leq$?  As you say yourself, a strict partial order would behave something like $<$ ... but by its name would still be considered a type of partial order. And that's exactly how I got to this question as well: why do we have to assume anything about its reflexive properties when it comes to partial orders? I am with William: it seems like only Antisymmetry and Transivitity are the real important ones.

Comment: Strict partial orders aren't partial orders. They are relations that may be writen as $\text{partial order}\land x\ne y$ @bram28

Comment: But from $\text{partial order} \land x \neq y$ I can logically infer $\text{partial order}$ @SaucyO'Path

Comment: @Bram28 I don't [see](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) how you would.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path I was just going by your earlier comment.... from $P \land Q$ I can infer $P$. But yeah, I was being facetious there. :P But look, my serious question is this:  Yes, I know *how* partial orders are defined. ... my question is *why* mathematicians defined them that way. That is, it seems that for any kind of 'order', all you need is anti-symmetry and transitivity: that alone will allow me to either line up all objects (in case of a total order), or at least create a lattice (and as such I would have a partial order). Reflexivity seems irrelevant to the basic idea of an order.

Comment: @Bram28 I don't know why exactly. I can see concepts of maximality and least upper bound being stated more naturally with $\le$, other than the fact that a number of proofs boil down to showing $a=b$ by showing $a\le b\land b\le a$. Anyways, the spirit of my answer is that the two notions are equally powerful and therefore you could choose one or the other (although I don't necessarily agree with your choice).

Comment: @Bram28 Notice however that the point I'm making is about chosing a transitive and *a*symmetric relation over a transitive, reflexive and *anti*symmetric relation. A statement on the truth value of all the $aRa$ must be made either way.