# Intuition for reflexive property of partial order relation

Tags: relations, order-theory

### Motivation for this question

I'm studying preference relation (at MWG - Microeconomic Theory), and there's a relation $\succ$ (strict preference relation) which is defined as above:

$x \succ y \iff x\succsim y \land y \not \succsim x$

Where $\succsim$ (prefence relation) is a complete and trasitive relation.

It's easy to prove that $\succ$ relation is transitive (follows from the transitivity of $\succsim$) and antisymmetric (it is vacuous truth, because there's never a pair $(x,y)$ such that $x \succ y \land y \succ x$)

For me looks like $\succ$ relation is very similar to a partial order relation, but it's not reflexive. So this question came to my mind.

### Why does the partial order relation needs to be reflexive?

What's the idea behind that? What results can be derived from the reflexive property that makes it relevant?

It's a bit strange for me because these two relations (a partial order and $\succ$) can be used to order some subsets from the original set.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2895169/why-does-a-partially-ordered-set-need-to-be-reflexive

Comment: This might help you